# How to break the while loop if the condition is False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a long function in which I am checking for different parameters and if any of the parameters is False, I don't want to execute the code further.

For your understanding, this is how I want to make it work

```py
Email = True
while(Email == True):
    print("Execute Me")
    Email = False # Break the while loop here
    print("Never execute me")
```

Here is the pseudo version of my code:

```py
def users_preferences(prefs):
    for pref in prefs:
        send_email = True
        while(send_email == True):
            # Set send_email = False if email is not verified and don't move to the next line
            # Set send_email = False if user's email is not a part of specific group
            ...
            ...
```

How can I break the loop if the condition is False at any point without further executing the code?

Edit: The problem with `break` statements is that it will become cumbersome to check the condition before running a new statement where you have number of statements

Comment: Unset `send_email` and condition won't be passed.

Comment: Have you looked into `break` statements?

Comment: @plum0 See the edit why I am not using break statement

Comment: What is the purpose of the `while` loop in your code?

Comment: @Muhaddis, it seems like you misuse `while` here. Could you elaborate how you want to apply this code?

Comment: @Muhaddis and there is no way to check all parameters at once? It seems like there would be an easier workflow to what you are trying to accomplish, but without the full use-case/code I don't think I can make a reccomendation

Comment: @OlvinRoght I was just experimenting with a while loop. I will appreciate if you have some better options. The purpose is to stop the further execution of the code. I have numbers of function to call ahead but the call is pointless if `send_email` is false at anywhere in the code.
CC: @nullptr

Comment: @Muhaddis, still not clear how it can be changed during code execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a normal `break` statement:

```
Email = True
while Email:
    print("Execute Me")
    Email = False # Break the while loop here
    if not Email:
        break
    print("Never execute me")
```

Edit: If the while loop doesn't do anything special, the code can be modified to be:

```
for pref in prefs:
    if not is_email_verified(email) or not is_user_in_group(user, group):
        continue
    send_email(email)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello your code needs to be better indented. Also why haven't you tried using break statement to get out of the loop?

```
Email = True
while Email:
    # do something
    break
# continue doing something
```

Comment: Not really an answer, should be a comment